# Use of nested foreach to display array inside another array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have the following data (item)

```
//------------------------------------------------------//
//| No | Item | Occurrence                             |//
//------------------------------------------------------//
//| 1  | A    | 222 | 3333 | 444 | 5555555             |//
//------------------------------------------------------//
//| 2  | B    | 11 | 77777 | 999                       |//
//------------------------------------------------------//
```

Occurrence is an array inside the data (item) and is dynamic

I would like my output to be as follows:

```
1   
A
222
3333
444
5555555
2   
B
11
77777
999
...............................................
```

Here's my code for print

```
foreach($data as $line_no => $line)
{
   foreach($line as $item_no => $item)
   {
      print $item.'<br>';
   }
}
```

Output for my code:

```
1
A
222    3333   444    5555555
2
B
11     77777  999
```

How should I code my program to get the output correctly?.. Kindly help..
Thanks

Comment: are you outputting in a console or what? because technically your code should work.

Comment: output using html.. its a web application. It doesn't work.. because values in occurrence are from another array that I implode into a string..

Comment: if you're imploding into a string why not implode with `"<br/>"` as the delimiter?

Comment: *facepalm*.. why didn't I think of that... Thanks so much @iam-decoder .. u just give me a very good solution.. >.< Thank you!!